# Block all crawler exept Google by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, server

Currently I'm using to block crawler on htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (AhrefsBot) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

But I want to set a code to block all crawlers except google bot

Comment: I assume you are still wanting regular users to access your site? In which case the solution is non-trivial, since you need to somehow differentiate real users from "all other crawlers" - and they could _look_ the same. Unless you have a specific reason, `robots.txt` would generally be the way to go.

Comment: I think {HTTP_USER_AGENT} is the way that I differentiate crawlers from regular users
I don't want to use robots.txt because of SEO reasons